# iOS6 automaticly adds contentInset to UITableView when keyboard shows up?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, keyboard

On iPhone, I found when keyboard shows up,  the system will set `contentInset` of tableView to `UIEdgeInsets(0, 0, 216, 0)` , because the keyboard height is 216. I think this is convienent when design an app only for the newest iOS, in the past, I have to calculate tableView size when keyboard came up by myself.

But I have to support iOS5, so I wanna know how to disable this automatic "favor" for me ? If I set 
`self.searchTipsController.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;` , the scroll indicator will not show. At last I have to detect system version to do handle it separately.

And I want to know from what version this feature begins? 6.0 or 6.1?

```
- (void) keyboardSizeChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* d = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGRect r = [[d objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    if(r.origin.y<[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)
    {
        CGRect convertRect = [self.view convertRect:r fromView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
        CGRect viewBounds = self.view.bounds;
        CGRect tipsFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, viewBounds.size.width, convertRect.origin.y);

        if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6.1"))
        {

        }else
        {
            self.searchTipsController.view.frame = tipsFrame;
            self.searchTipsController.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        }
    }
}
```

I change my code, when keyboard raises, remove the tableview then add it back, this time it looks right..

```
- (void) keyboardSizeChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* d = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGRect r = [[d objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    if(r.origin.y<[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)
    {
        CGRect convertRect = [self.view convertRect:r fromView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
        CGRect viewBounds = self.view.bounds;
        CGRect tipsFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, viewBounds.size.width, convertRect.origin.y);


        self.searchTipsController.view.frame = tipsFrame;
        self.searchTipsController.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

        [self.searchTipsController.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view addSubview:self.searchTipsController.view];

    }
}
```

But I still hope some one can answer my question, thanks.

Comment: Test it using the simulator on each iOS version. I'll say it started in iOS6 maybe it has something to do with state preservation : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIScrollView

Comment: It's not the iOS 6 doing that, it is `UITableViewController` and it's working on older versions. However if you are using `UIViewController` you have to manually manage that regardless of OS version.

Comment: I run same code on 5.1 simulator, this does not happen.

Comment: It happens, something else must be wrong.

Comment: Alright, I make a mistake.... thanks  Desdenova